# Replacing System.err.println in quick debug of short code examples

Tags: java, debugging

I have to write short code samples for which using an IDE is overkill; I use Gedit. For debugging purposes, I've been using a quick method `dbgm`. Some Google search has thrown up similar suggestions:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Tyle {

public Tyle() {
}

/**
* @param debugmessage
* This method takes any debugmessage and prints the string version
* to System.err.println
*/
private static void dbgm(Object debugmessage) {
    System.err.println(debugmessage.toString());
}

/**
* @param number
*/
public static int cube(int i) {
    int cube;
    cube=i*i*i;
    dbgm(cube); //debug message
    return cube;
}

public static void main(String [] args){
    System.out.print("Enter number: ");
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    int inp = s.nextInt();
    Tyle.cube(inp);
    s.close();
}
}
```

This has its merits, I can search for `dbgm`, and leave any bona fide `System.out.println()` calls alone.

But I am not at all sure if using a method like this is good practice, especially when in debug mode. I have been thinking of using something akin to generics, where I  provide a type rather than just specify `Object` (it feels risky) and depend on `toString()`.

I can use `assert` in this simplistic example, but there can be much more complex situations during user studies. Such as if `number` is based on user input. There can also be situations where I am trying to just quickly check that some parameters are giving expected values.

Is there a way to safely write a variant of the `dbgm` method where I can get the appropriate descriptor, specifically if for example its a custom object? I want to keep reusing the solution to this in a sort of 'production' environment.

Is there a right way?

Comment: Why not use an actual logging framework like [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/) or [logback](http://logback.qos.ch/)?

Comment: what part of this do you think might not be good practice for small code?

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans 1. using one custom method to use as a debug sink seems logical rather than writing long lines (DRY). 2. It actually makes my code more readable. the `dbgm` can be a marker.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch: to specify, I don't really need very detailed logging.

Comment: @CoriolisForce If you are concerned about *good* (or even *best*) *practices* then you should use a logging framework to start with.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Would you recommend a logging framework for the code-length in the example?

Comment: @CoriolisForce I'd probably use [Simple Logging Facade for Java](http://www.slf4j.org/) sine it allows you to choose implementation at deployment time.

Comment: @CoriolisForce I asked what made you think it might *not* be good practice, not why you thought it was good practice =) (because if you don't want a log4j solution, it totally makes sense to use, especially when you have a tiny amount of code)

Comment: @Mike'Pomax'Kamermans :-) I couldn't think of any. Open to ideas.

Comment: Why are you passing `Object` to `dbgm()`? Isn't it a message and you always need `String`?

Comment: @Scadge The reason I need this is to check properties of variables on the fly, and not error messages. These properties might not be strings.

Comment: Then you might consider a generic method for better safety.

Answer (score 0):

If the code samples you are writing consists of a single java files, I'll recommend not using a `dbmg` method, just using `System.our/System.err` print methods explicitly. Using a custom logging abstraction will probably complicate the sample code with unnecessary details.

However, if:

- Others are going to use your code sample in other projects.
- You code sample will eventually end up in production.
- You code sample is bundled in a project (using multiple files and dependency management).

Then don't reinvent the wheel, use a Logging framework.